# What is it called when a benzene ring loses a hydrogen atom?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Does not get substituted by another group it just gets removed  (so not aryl) what is it? Like when two benzene rings lose one H atom each we get arylene? Whats another name for it? I just need the name for when the atom is removed and NOT subtituted 
Thank you

Edit: thats not the answer I asked for
I asked what it was called when it lost the hydrogen atom and you say its aryl but thats when a group is in place of the lost atom

Answer (score 0):

The name of the benzene minus a hydrogen is called a phenyl group (C6H5). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenyl_group Look this page up for more information. The question you've asked is very similar to the one that @Gaurang has commented, so just be careful when you ask questions on here. Hope this helps

Comment: Is that when it doesnt get subtituted by a functional group?

Comment: Yes, it says in the wiki page as well.

Comment: But wheb I read it it says that the "ar" refers to the group

Comment: Ar refers to aryl, which is a broader denotation of the group. Phenyl I believe is the correct/ more used term.